# Dynamically edit a table td text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `list` with professor's names.
'Inside' each professor, I have a `sublist` with the `disciplines` they teach. Everything is brought from database...
When I expand a professor's disciplines, I'd like to fill the table with those disciplines.
The  hard part is: I need to insert those disciplines in the right time.
Every discipline has it's `ID` and its `Time`.
As you can see [Here](http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/zGQMpw). At first, this table will be empty, filled only with the time of the classes (I filled with disciplines only for example).

If you check the HTML, you'll see that I already have the professors and
disciplines ID, in `data-id=""`.

How may I insert those disciplines in the right place of the table, by the time that discipline is taught in the moment I expand that professor's discipline.  Also, later I'll need to place two or three disciplines in the same TD space, exactly like google's agenda.
 I tried to work with `JQuery eq()` but I can't make it work.

**UPDATE**
This is what I did with `JQuery.eq()`:

```
$( "body" ).find( "table tr td" ).eq( 2 ).addClass( "blue" );
```

I'm able to apply that class correctly, but how may I select the correct one according to the discipline's time ? (The Time will be taken from database with its ID).

Do I use `Ajax` to get the discipline's time from database ?
Do I add the discipline's time when I'm filling the sublist as a custom atribute, like `data-time=""`, then reuse it to fill the table ?
Do I add some custom class for each row ?
Do I make a lot of `IF`s statements?

Comment: Just let me know the reason for downvote, so the mistake wont happen again. Thanks.

Comment: (not the downvoter but I'm quite near to be one) - Always try to include the relevant **minimal** code right into your question. You have at your disposition all the needed Code and Snippet tools.  P.S: what are the checkboxes for?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan All the I did is in the codepen, what I tried with `JQuery.eq()` is nothing, I just need some help to understand how to select the right place (add a custom class for each row, make some if statements..). When I expand one professor, I'll display his disciplines, right? When I expand a second professor, his disciplines will take place on the table, but If the checkbox is checked, it will 'lock' those disciplines there and I'll need to show those disciplines simultaneously.

Comment: Just added some update.

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing what you're asking. I'd recommend mapping the header column names as it's easier to reference a table cell...

```
var $table = $('#myTable'), cols = getColumnNames();

// use map function to get an array containing column names
function getColumnNames(){  
    var $header = $('thead th', $table);
    return $header.map(function(){ return $(this).text(); }).get();
}

// now easier to get a table cell, by passing the row and column name
function getCell($row, colName){            
    var index = cols.indexOf(colName);
    return $row.find('td:eq(' + index + ')');
}

// loop through rows and choose which cell to process
function loopThroughRows(){ 

    var $row, $cell, $rows = $table.find('tr');

    $rows.each(function(){
        $row  = $(this);
        $cell = getCell($row, 'Segunda-Feira');
        // do stuff with $cell
    });
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest adding a timestamp to data-id for each row, it would be easier to do the searching on the client, rather than hitting the DB with an Ajax request.

Comment: You mean add the discipline time for each row ?

Comment: You could add some king of unique ID to each rows data-id; not sure what as I'm confused by the original question, or you could you jQuery's data function (https://api.jquery.com/data/) to attach info to each row and / or professor.

Comment: I already added the Discipline and professor ID for each row. What I don't know is how to  add those disciplines on the table and on the right place (according to discipline time, 8h:30 ~ 10h:30, 10h30 ~ 12h30 ...). Add this time in `data-time=""` ?I want to know the right way to do it.

Comment: I don't see how the table maps to the professors? You only list the subject and times. How are the times related to a professors subject? Perhaps you need another table.